# neo4j not cluing into the multiple labels

Tags: neo4j

My DB consists of two node groups (labels) x and y.  y nodes also have additional labels (colors: blue, red, green, etc).

My query is:
`MATCH (n1:y)-->(n2:x)<--(n3:blue) RETURN n2.idx`

The profile shows an expand for n3 without any reference to it being blue, resulting in 12,000 DB hits, pushing out 12,000 rows.  The next stage is a filter for blue, resulting in nearly 24,000 DB hits returning 1,036 rows.

I have constraints on both `idx` and `idy` being unique, and I have the index on each of the colors.

I have tried using a color attribute on the y nodes, changing the query to the following, without any difference in the profile.
`MATCH (n1:y)-->(n2:x)<--(n3:y {color:blue}) RETURN n2.idx`

I've tried `using index n3:blue(idy)` before the `RETURN` statement, but that gives me a syntax error.  I'm still trying to `decypher` that (pardon the pun).
How can I avoid the stage db hit bloat described above, and have it just start with only blue nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [scan hint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/using/#query-using-scan-hint) to start using a label scan on `n3`.

```
MATCH (n1:y)-->(n2:x)<--(n3:blue) 
USING SCAN n3:blue
RETURN n2.idx
```

Also, this may produce duplicates if :x nodes can have multiple relationships to :y nodes or :blue nodes. If you only want :x nodes that have a connection to a :y node, then you might try this instead:

```
MATCH (n2:x)<--(n3:blue) 
USING SCAN n3:blue
WHERE (:y)-->(n2)
WITH DISTINCT n2
RETURN n2.idx
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, that causes many more hits to find all of the n3 nodes with label blue.  There are a lot of them.  Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong.

Comment: First, we want all edges that exist from n3:blue to n2:x nodes that are first found by the (n1)-->(n2) relationship.  So, for the performance issue of the (n2)<--(n3:blue), in the expand portion, It appears to be just gathering the relationship list getting 12000 hits, but what are those hits?  I'm now thinking that is just building up the list of a (n3) ids from the relationship.  The next 12000 hits in the filter is the db finding the labels of those first hits.  So then there is no means to have the expand step only go to blue nodes unless I 1st do the huge blue lookup.  right?

Comment: From a starting node, there is no way to tell anything about the node it's connected to without expanding to it, then filtering in some way (such as to get only nodes with a certain label). However, if you use a specific relationship type just to nodes with those labels, then you can avoid the db hits and filtering since nodes know their relationship types and can only traverse the ones with that particular type.